# Silverlight 4: How to reference class from another assembly

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, assemblies

In XAML-file of the SquadView page (VfmElitaSilverlightClientView.Pages.SquadView) I am using custom value converter. XAML-file is in "VfmElitaSilverlightClientView" namespace. Separate folder was created for converter and it is in "VfmElitaSilverlightClientView.Converter" namespace (in the same assembly). To use converter following code is used in XAML:

```
xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:VfmElitaSilverlightClientView.Converter"
...
<NavigationControls:Page.Resources>
    <Converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="resourceBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</NavigationControls:Page.Resources>
```

All works fine. Here I want to move converter class into a custom separate assembly "SilverlightCommonView" and class himself will be in "SilverlightCommonView.Converter" namespace. The XAML code is changed to the following:

```
xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:SilverlightCommonView.Converter;assembly=SilverlightCommonView" 
...
<NavigationControls:Page.Resources>
    <Converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="resourceBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</NavigationControls:Page.Resources>
```

In this case when application throws following exception:

> An unhandled exception ('Unhandled
>   Error in Silverlight Application...
>   Code: 4004 Category:
>   ManagedRuntimeError Message:
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException:
>   Resolution of dependency failed, type="VfmElitaSilverlightClientView.Pages.SquadView",
>   name="(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: Calling constructor
>   VfmElitaSilverlightClientView.Pages.SquadView(). Exception is: XamlParseException -
>   The type 'BooleanToVisibilityConverter' was not found because
>   'cl...:SilverlightCommonView.Converter;assembly=SilverlightCommonView'
>   is an unknown namespace.

It's unclear why specified namespace is unknown (those assembly is referenced by the current one).

Please advise.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: FYI your second sample XAML is wrong, though I suspect that's a copy paste error while asking this question since you have an Exception that seems to indicateyou did it right in your actual application. You're using "Converter:" and not "CommonConverter2:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet you do not have an assembly reference to your shared/common project from your application project.

Comment: You was almost right. Reference was absent, but not in assembly that contained view class, but in application that references to "view"-assembly. When reference to 'SilverlightCommonView' was added into 'Application' project - problem was resolved. Thanks again, your answer gave me ability to be more confident in the XAML source code.

Comment: No, that's what I said. "...TO your shared/common project FROM your application...". So rephrased, your application needed a reference to the common project.